# Tool to generate request body of a rest ws?

Tags: rest

I have a rest service that can be reached with a post request.

But There's many complex types as parameters, does it exists some tools that can generate the body request for me ?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards

Comment: Could you post up an example of the request body that you want to generate?

Comment: I can't because that's what I want to generate. I thought that there were tools to generate the xml body. Because I have to find each xml value of the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Tim,
you might want to look at the Sun implementation of JAX-RS (called Jersey). It comes with a client side API and makes use of the standard JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter classes. There is also support for JAXB-based generation of XML from domain objects.

Jersey: http://jersey.java.net/

Besides that: yes, you should provide more details to receive a better answer. I also have a hunch that your REST Web service might not be that RESTful after all given that you say it 'can be reached with POST'. That suggest other methods are not supported - is that true?

Jan

Comment: Yes, it's true, only post is allowed on the methods